# How to get your merge request up2date in gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

i do have a quite trivial git-related question, but for some reason I was not able to find a satisfactory answer by myself and I feel embarrassed to ask my colleagues.

I also have to say, that I do generally understand git but i am new to gitlab (which is used in my company).

So my problem is the following: I made a change request for a bug fix two weeks ago. The review took some time and only yesterday I managed to address the review comments. For this i checked out the change request branch did my changes and pushed it back. In the meantime the remote master diverged quite a lot and requires me to do somethin about it.

I my previous company we used a different workflow and i would just rebase my branch on top of the master and push. With gitlab one rather merges the master branch into the feature branch (at least that is what i heard). When i do that it creates a huuuuuuuge commit which consist of the delta between my feature branch (based on the master 2 weeks ago) and the current master.

I am not sure, whether that is the best way or a way at all. Can anyone tell me (or hint me to some good tutorial) how i can resolve my mess?

Comment: Yes, reverse merge is a very good way to handle possible conflicts before a forward merge. There is no such thing as “a huuuuuuuge commit”; the diff may be extensive but that is just a description, while commits are just a snapshot of all your files and are all about the same “size”.

Comment: I sometimes merge master into my own branch first and fix all the conflicts. While that looks like a big change, I find it leaves a smaller trail on the master branch when I afterwards merge my branch into it.

Answer (score 0):

That's sounds tedious, but a good way to make sure the branch is up to date with the current master.

Here's one resource:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/